# Background colour in opengl

Tags: c, opengl, glut

I want to change the background color of the window after pressing the button, but my program doesn't work, can somebody tell me why?

```c
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  glutInit(&argc, argv);
  glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_SINGLE | GLUT_RGB);
  glutInitWindowSize(800, 600);
  glutInitWindowPosition(300,50);
  glutCreateWindow("GLRect");
        
  glClearColor(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);   <---
    
  glutDisplayFunc(RenderScene);
  glutReshapeFunc(ChangeSize);
  glutMainLoop();
    
  system("pause");
  glClearColor(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);   <---
    
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: After pressing "what button"?

Comment: Since `glutMainLoop()` will never return how do you expect to get to your `system("pause")` statement and the second `glClearColor` call?

Comment: @tafa: how can I change my code to see this effect?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

`glClearColor` does not do any clearing itself -- it just sets what the color will be when you do actually clear. To do the clearing itself, you need to call `glClear` with (at least) `COLOR_BUFFER_BIT`.

Edit: it's been quite a while since I used glut, so the details of this could be wrong, but if memory serves, to change the screen color in response to pressing a key on the keyboard, you'd do something like this:

```
void keyboard (unsigned char key, int x, int y)
{
    // we'll switch between red and blue when the user presses a key:
    GLfloat colors[][3] = { { 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f}, {1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f } };
    static int back;

    switch (key) {
    case 27: 
        exit(0);
    default:
        back ^= 1;
        glClearColor(colors[back][0], colors[back][1], colors[back][2], 1.0f);
        glutPostRedisplay();
    }
}

void draw() { 
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    // other drawing here...
}

int main() { 

    // glutInit, glutInitDisplayMode, etc.

     glutDisplayFunc(draw);
     glutKeyboardFunc(keyboard);
     glutMainLoop();
}
```

Basically, you do all your drawing in whatever function you pass to `glutDisplayFunc`. Almost anything else just changes the state, then calls `PostRedisplayFunc();` to tell glut that the window needs to be redrawn. Warning: as I said, it's been a while since I used glut and I haven't tested this code. It shows the general structure of a glut program to the best of my recollection, but don't expect it to work exactly as-is.

Comment: I did it,but it still doesn't work, may be problem with glutMainLoop?

Comment: This solution is fine. Try using double buffer? glutMainLoop is fine. Tell me if it works with double buffering

Answer (score 0):

I would imagine you don't have an OpenGL context at that point that you call `glClearColor`.

But...

...I've never used glut before so a quick look at the [docs](http://www.opengl.org/resources/libraries/glut/spec3/spec3.html) suggests that you will actually have a context after `glutCreateWindow` so perhaps that's not it.

As my comment on your question says I'm curious about the second call to `glClearColor` and how you think you will reach it. That's more likely the cause of the problem. To do anything on a key press I believe you would have to register a callback using `glutKeyboardFunc`.

Comment: sorry, but I didn't understand, I'm beginner